# How the shadowsocks client make all the Internet request through the client?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, agent

When I use the shadowsock's client on windows, and I make it the global agent.

Then, whatever I use Fixfox or chrome, I could get the result I want.

I want to know , how the client make the other software use the Internet through it ? Could someone tell the knowledge about this?

Comment: Use chorme  will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

on unix system, using proxychains

#### intall [proxychains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng)

ubuntu

`sudo apt-get install proxychains`

mac os x

`brew install proxychains`

[from source code](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng)

#### Edit proxychains config

add below line to `/etc/proxychains.conf` on linux or `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf` on mac

```
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080 # on linux
socks5  127.0.0.1 1086 # on mac
```

Don't forget remove remove socks4 if exits

#### Usage

on linux

```
proxychains wget https://www.google.com
proxychains google-chrome
```

on mac

```
proxychains4 wget https://www.google.com
```